# Mongodb, one to many relationship nested

Tags: mongodb

**Context**

I have, in my code, many objects, corresponding to :

- Object
- Zone (that has a list of Objects)
- Floor(that has a list of Zones)
- Building(that has a list of Floors)
- Client
- Site(that has a list of Buildings and a list of Clients)
- Agency (that has a list of sites)
- Group (that has a list of agencies)

According to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/ , it could be a good idea to have list and not directly references on another collection.

**Question**

But I was wondering, in my case, where I only have one to many relationships, if it was a good idea to nest everything in a single collection.

Can you tell me if it could be okay, and if it is, when should I split my data in different collections so ?